# Android 13 compliance target date

Tags: android, google-play-console, mobile-application

Our current app which is live in google play is targeting Android 12, and we have a question, if we get an extension from 31, Aug 2023 to 1st, Nov 2023 to update our app, will we still be able to update our app with Android 12 between these dates 31, Aug 2023 to 1st, Nov 2023?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can, if you are updating the app you must target `Android 13 (API level 33)` after _August 31, 2023_. The extension request is to keep the current application available in Google Play to devices running on Android 13 and above.